Creating One-to-Many relationships in Geopackages
The question is not new but still there is no clear answer.
A very detailed expression of the question was given by nr_aus (https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/165549/nr-aus)
at:
Creating relationships at the database level using QGIS and Geopackages
What we know is how to use the "OGC GeoPackage Related Tables Extension" to handle Many-To-Many Relationships that are bautilfully handled also in QGIS UI (https://docs.ogc.org/is/18-000/18-000.html#_many_to_many)
Still there seems to be no clear way to get to the same level of effectiveness for One-To-Many Relationships in Geopackage.
Defining constraint as FOREIGN KEYs in CREATE TABLE statements in SQLite tools like DBeaver let enforce the data validity but still the 'relation' does not emerge in the UI of tools like QGIS.
Is there any way to create a One-To-Many Relatioship in a Geopackage as it is now possible in OpentFileGDB (ESRI File Geodatabase)?

Which specific part of the "effectiveness" do you think is missing? Your question might be easier to answer if you posed a specific task that doesn't work with what you have. In addition, can you clarify whether you think this is a GeoPackage standards problem, or is this more a UI / implementation (e.g. QGIS) question?

Dear @BradHards my hope was to find a clean workflow to handle One-to_Many relationships in GeoPackage as it exists for Many-to-Many ones.
You are right as for asking whether mine is a UI question or what but, in a user perspective there is no distance between what a Geopackage can "do" and the tool (e.g. QGIS) that allow them to leverage those capabilities.
This is maybe clearer if we compare GeoPacakge and ESRI File Geodatabase, now accessible also in writing thanks to OpenFileGDB driver in GDAL 3.7. [continues..]

ESRI FIle Geodatabase has its way to store One-to-Many relationships and tools (e.g.: QGIS v.3.36) allow their creation and usage. This is NOT possible with Geopackage but the user has to forcefully go through a Many-to-Many relationship.
This is definitely not an 'effective' workflow also because it requires people to spot this reference (https://docs.ogc.org/per/17-093r1.html#_cardinality) to start suspecting it is like that not as fora bug but 'by design', for a decision taken back in 2018.
